# Configure Remote Desktop Desktop based on Group

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, remote-desktop

I have a few different AD groups accessing the same remote desktop server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and I need to configure each desktop so that every user in the same group has the same icons appear on their desktop.  For instance users in group X need a shortcut to "App A" to open on port 1111 and a shortcut to "App B", while users in Group Y need a shortcut to "App A" to open on port 2222 and a shortcut to "App C".

Is there a way to have the desktop configuration automatically setup for a client based on what group they're a member of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Group Policy Preferences with Item-Level Targeting to create the shortcuts for each group of users.